# Circular orbit in a stationary, axially symmetric spacetime

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, orbital-motion, geodesics

From Poisson's, A Relativists Toolkit, problem 1.12 on page 27:

> "A particle moving on a circular oribit in a stationary, axially symmetric spacetime is subjected to a dissipative force which drives it to another, slightly smaller, circular orbit. During the transition, the particle loses an amount $\delta \tilde{E}$ of orbital energy (per unit rest mass), and an amount $\delta \tilde{L}$ of orbital angular momentum (per unit rest mass). You are asked to prove these quantities are related by $\delta \tilde{E} = \Omega \delta \tilde{L}$, where $\Omega$ is the particle's original angular velocity. By "circular orbit", we mean that the particle has a four-velocity given by
> \begin{align*}
>     u^a &= \gamma(\xi^a_{(t)} + \Omega \xi^a_{(\phi)})
> \end{align*}
> where $\xi_{(t)}^a$ and $\xi_{(\phi)}^a$ are the spacetime's timelike and rotational Killing vectors, respectively; $\Omega$ and $\gamma$ are constants.
> You may proceed along the following lines: First, express $\gamma$ in terms of $\tilde{E}$ and $\tilde{L}$. Second, find an expression for $\delta u^a$, the change in the four-velocity as the particle goes from its original orbit to its final orbit. Third, prove the relation
> \begin{align*}
>     u^a \delta u_a &= \gamma(\delta \tilde{E} - \Omega \delta \tilde{L}) 
> \end{align*}
> from which the theorem follows."

ATTEMPT:

By definition, $\tilde{E} = - u \cdot \xi_{(t)}$ and $\tilde{L} = u \cdot \xi_{(\phi)}$.

So if we assume $\xi_{(t)} \cdot \xi_{(t)} = -1$ and $\xi_{(\phi)} \cdot \xi_{(\phi)} = 1$, we can see that

\begin{align*}
    \tilde{E} &= - u \cdot \xi_{(t)} \\
    &= \gamma(1 - \Omega \xi_{(\phi)} \cdot \xi_{(t)})
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
    \tilde{L} &= u \cdot \xi_{(\phi)} \\
    &= \gamma(\xi_{(t)}\cdot \xi_{(\phi) } + \Omega)
\end{align*}

And so, eliminating $\xi_{(t)} \cdot \xi_{(\phi)}$, we get

\begin{align*}
    \gamma &= \frac{\tilde{E} + \Omega \tilde{L}}{1 + \Omega^2}.
\end{align*}

But I don't know how to proceed to get an expression for $\delta u^a$.

I know that $u \cdot u = -1$, but I don't see how that helps.

Also, we are told above $\Omega$ and $\gamma$ are constant, but is this only on a given orbit?

Also, if $\Omega$ and $\gamma$ are constant, then it looks like I could just take the "delta" of both sides of the expression I have for $\gamma$ and get that $\delta \tilde{E} + \Omega \delta \tilde{L} = 0$.

Clarifying comments on how to approach this would be appreciated.